# Overloading an Abstract method in Java?

Tags: java, class, interface, overloading, abstract-class

I have the following interface and abstract class:

```
public interface DataExporter {
    MultipartFile export() throws IOException;
}


public abstract class AbstractExporter<T> implements DataExporter {
    protected abstract Iterable<T> getData();
}
```

I call `getData()` method in my exporter class as shown below:

```
public class EmployeeExporter extends AbstractExporter<EmployeeDTO> {
    
    protected Iterable<EmployeeDTO> getData() {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

However, in another class e.g. ManagerExporter, I need to pass parameter to the `getData()` method:

```
public class ManagerExporter extends AbstractExporter<ManagerDTO> {
    
    protected Iterable<ManagerDTO> getData(UUID uuid) {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

I think overloading that method in `AbstractExporter` is not a good idea,
because in that case `EmployeeExporter` will need to implement it even if it does not use it. So, what is the most proper approach to use `getData()` method with & without parameter?

**Note**: I might also need other implementations that require multiple parameters e.g. `protected Iterable<ManagerDTO> getData(UUID uuid, UUID departmentUuid, UUID staffUuid)`. In this case, should I need to use an Object array, etc. like `Object[]`?

Comment: Does anybody else have no experience with interface / abstract classes?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Any reply pls?

Comment: If you need different method signatures, then you shouldn't extend the same abstract class.

Comment: @LouisWasserman In this case, what should I do? Could you pls post an answer to explain your suggestion?

Comment: What is the uuid parameter an id for?  Does it identify which Manager or something else?  Is it possible that this should be passed to the ManagerExporter constructor rather than the getData() method?  Or do you need to be able to export different sets of data from a single instance of ManagerExporter?

Comment: @DaveS Thanks for reply, but you pointed the most unnecessary point, because it does not make any sense. I just gave it to show the same method also need to take parameter. You can think that parameter whatever you want. Instead, you may concentrate on the real problem.

Comment: Your real problem is not about coding, you understand the coding part perfectly.  All methods declared in the abstract class must be implemented by all subclasses.  Your real problem is class responsibilities.  Who should be responsible for making the UUID available to the implementation of getData() in the subclass, the caller of getData() or another class?  You don't need to tell me but you need to have another look at your design and ask yourself these questions.  Or, you could consider this purely a coding problem, declare the method as getData( Object[] ) and see how that turns out : )

Answer (score 2):

If you need different method signatures, then you shouldn't extend the same abstract class.

So...just don't bother.

```
public interface DataExporter {
    MultipartFile export() throws IOException;
}

public class EmployeeExporter implements DataExporter {
    protected Iterable<EmployeeDTO> getData() {
        // code omitted
    }
}
public class ManagerExporter implements DataExporter {   
    protected Iterable<ManagerDTO> getData(UUID uuid) {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need 2 abstract methods as `protected abstract Iterable<T> getData();` and `protected abstract Iterable<T> getData(UUID uuid);` in `AbstractExporter` class?

Comment: No.  I mean that you need zero abstract methods, and zero abstract classes, and that you should delete the `AbstractExporter` class entirely based on what you've told us.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then should I use 2 method in the interface? Could you pls add the interface and other class that I posted? I am confused.

Comment: No.  The interface should not be changed.  No type should have both these methods.

Comment: Could you pls add the interface and other class that I posted?

Comment: I added the interface, which isn't changed at all.  There is no other class you posted except AbstractExporter, which as I said, you should delete.

Comment: There isn't anything in this answer that's hidden, or that I haven't shown you.  Nothing is missing.  This is the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to use your DataExporter. If you want to use both methods of this class, then you have to add a method in all implementations, otherwise, you just do not need one of these methods in the parent class.

Comment: What about posting an example code covering all of the classes in my question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the code where you are calling `getData()`.

In your original question you said "I call `getData()` method in my exporter class as shown below".  But what you show below is not a call, it's a concrete implementation of the abstract method.

The `getData()` method is protected so it's only being called by AbstractExporter or its subclasses.  Does AbstractExporter have at least one concrete method implementation that calls `getData()`?

If not then you can simply remove `getData()` from that abstract class.  All calls to `getData()` are in the sub-classes and they presumably know the right arguments to pass.  The `getData()` method can be removed from the abstract class and declared (possibly as private) in the concrete implementation classes.

```
public interface DataExporter {
    MultipartFile export() throws IOException;
}

public abstract class AbstractExporter<T> implements DataExporter {
    // No call to getData() occurs anywhere in this class
}

public class EmployeeExporter extends AbstractExporter<EmployeeDTO> {

    private Iterable<EmployeeDTO> getData() {
        // code omitted
    }
}

public class ManagerExporter extends AbstractExporter<ManagerDTO> {

    private Iterable<ManagerDTO> getData(UUID uuid) {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

If AbstractExporter contains calls to `getData()` then how does it determine what arguments it should pass to that method?  Something smells fishy.  Instances of AbstractExporter can be used interchangeably.  Each subclass should know how to perform `getData()` using the same set of parameters.  If ManagerExporter requires a UUID to perform its export then you could possibly assign that value when the instance is constructed rather than passing it as an argument to `getData()`.

```
public interface DataExporter {
    MultipartFile export() throws IOException;
}

public abstract class AbstractExporter<T> implements DataExporter {
    protected abstract Iterable<T> getData();

    public MultipartFile export() throws IOException {
        // Call to getData() occurs here or somewhere else in this class
    }
}

public class EmployeeExporter extends AbstractExporter<EmployeeDTO> {

    protected Iterable<EmployeeDTO> getData() {
        // code omitted
    }
}

public class ManagerExporter extends AbstractExporter<ManagerDTO> {
    private uuid;
    public ManagerExporter( UUID uuid ) {
        // The uuid is determined when the object is constructed
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
    protected Iterable<ManagerDTO> getData() {
        // Use this.uuid in my implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations, but again it would be better you just concentrate on the code. I may not explain well, but the code shows everything. I think the issue is clear from looking the code and I just want to overload the getData() method with/without parameter. Does not matter why I use the parameter, nor the type of parameter.